# ItemConsolidatedQuery Find by Custom Field

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

In QuickBooks Desktop, I have an inventory item with a custom field called code. The value of the code is 12345. I need to pull a inventory item where the custom field code is 12345.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ItemConsolidatedQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><CustomFieldEnable>true</CustomFieldEnable><NameContains>temple</NameContains></ItemConsolidatedQuery>
```

I know the item's name, so I tried to query by it. There are 3 items with the same name, so I attempted to query them later. I am unable to see any custom field data:

http://pastebin.com/FBD1na0s

I know that the custom field exists. Here is my C# code:

```
            Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemConsolidatedQuery itQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemConsolidatedQuery();
        itQuery.NameContains = "temple";
        itQuery.CustomFieldEnable = true;
        itQuery.CustomFieldEnableSpecified = true;
        itQuery.CustomFieldFilter = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.customFieldFilterEnumType.Include;
        var itemsList = itQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemConsolidated>(ds.ServiceContext);
```

Is there a C# example to query custom fields in QBD?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this line:

itQuery.CustomFieldFilterSpecified = true;

Also, custom fields in QB are secured by OwnerID.  Probably theOwnerID must be specified in itQuery.CustomFieldQueryParam; I haven't experimented with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Need to include OwnerIDList in the request. See the OSR for examples.

Comment: Thank you, but I am referring to the Intuit Partner Platform API.